# Index Fabric (layered Patricia trie)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, indexing, patricia-trie

I'm currently trying to implement the Index Fabric for a dna sequence data search system:

[Index fabric algorithm](http://xml.coverpages.org/ShadmonVLDB2001.pdf)

I could implement the normal patricia trie, but I still couldn't understand how to add layers.  I also tried google but couldn't find enough information about adding layers to the patricia trie there either.  In the paper mentioned above they came straightly with the layered trie which seems like witchcraft to me (just kidding, last part). 
Does anyone have experience in implementing the Index Fabric architecture, and if so, can you guys kindly share your experience with me?

Thanks in advance
Nuwan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you at all familiar with B-trees? Detailed descriptions of B-trees shouldn't be hard to come by, and the Index Fabric really isn't much more than a mash-up of a Patricia trie and a B-tree.

Comment: Thanks Dave. You really provided me a path to travel. I hope you don't mind me asking some questions later.

Nuwan